# Facing an issue with R, DataframeSource error

Tags: r, dataframe, text

I have just started learning R and I am facing an issue. i have already managed to load my dataframe into "txt", also have installed tm, sentimentr and SnowballC packages but when I run this programme, The error message is
Error in DataframeSource(txt) :
all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE*

the code is

```
#setting df as working file

txt = read.csv("xxx.csv")

#creating corpus for data frame

comments_corpus= VCorpus(DataframeSource(txt))

comments = comments_corpus

comments = tm_map(comments, content_transformer(tolower))

comments = tm_map(comments, removePunctuation)

comments = tm_map(comments, removeNumbers)
```

Comment: What is in your .csv file? Specifically, is its first column "doc_id"?

Comment: Hello, you must share a sample of your data and build a reproducible example to make possible an answer to be given.

Comment: @IdoSarig my first column is labelled as airline, as i am doing a project on airline customer satisfaction.

Comment: @RicVillalba hello ric, how shall i share the sample of my data? I am not too familiar with stackover flow. but my columns are airline, overall score, author, review data in this sequence

Comment: Ok, that's the issue - you need to have a column labeled "doc_id" if you want to use DataframeSource. As an alternative, if all you are trying to do is create a DF out of the csv, this should do the trick:   my_df <-tibble(txt)

Comment: @IdoSarig I have tried tibble but it doesn't seem to work, will it be easier if i just add in the doc_id?

Comment: Adding that column will certainly fix your current error message. What doesn't work with the tibble?

Comment: @IdoSarig i have added doc_id manually on my excel sheet and removed NA rows but it still does not seem to work as well. i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataframeSource(x)` expects the first column in x to be named "doc_id" and contain a unique string identifier. It looks like that's not the case in your txt file, which gets passed to DataframeSource